# Pythonic way to extract the file name and its parent directory from the full file path?

Tags: python, path, directory

We have the full path of the file:

```
/dir1/dir2/dir3/sample_file.tgz
```

Basically, I would like to end up with this string:

```
dir3/sample_file.tgz
```

We can solve it with `regex` or with `.split("/")` and then take and concatenate  the last two items in the list.....but I am wondering if we can do this more stylish with `os.path.dirname()` or something like that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import os
full_filename = "/path/to/file.txt"
fname = os.path.basename(full_filename)
onedir = os.path.join(os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(full_filename)), os.path.basename(full_filename))
```

no one ever said os.path was pretty to use, but it ought to do the correct thing regardless of platform.

If you're in python3.4 (or higher, presumably), there's a `pathlib`:

```
import os
import pathlib
p = pathlib.Path("/foo/bar/baz/txt")
onedir = os.path.join(*p.parts[-2:])
```

Comment: Even better if you keep it to pathlib all the way: `onedir = pathlib.Path(*p.parts[-2:])`